# Devise omniauth + facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I have a problem with auth by Facebook, Twitter, G+ and Linkedin. I tried to make auth with Facebook using their SDK. I added in devise config for Facebook { provider_ignores_state: true }.

JS now looks like:

```
$(function(){
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : APP_ID,
      status     : true,
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
  };

 (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  $('.facebook-auth').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
        var signedRequest = response.authResponse.signedRequest

        FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,username,email,picture', function(response) {
          window.location.href = '/users/auth/facebook/callback?image=' + response.picture.data.url + '&token=' + access_token + '&id=' +response.id + '&username=' + response.username + '&name=' + response.name + '&email=' + response.email + '&signed_request=' + signedRequest
        });
      }
    }, {scope: 'email,user_activities,friends_activities,user_likes,friends_likes,user_groups,user_photos,user_status,friends_status,read_stream,offline_access,read_friendlists,user_subscriptions,friends_subscriptions,manage_pages'});
  });
});
```

Auth works ok, all data received but auth using other social networks not works anymore. Error: Not found. Authentication passthru. 
After server reboot all ok. Then try to signup using Facebook again and same error appears.
Can you advice why it is and how to fix it?

devise (3.2.3)
omniauth (1.1.4)
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)